# Is this AM-GM application correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification

I have got an inequality down to proving that: if $a,b,c$ are positive reals that satisfy $a+b+c=1$, then $$\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{a}}+\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{b}}+\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{c}}\ge \frac{9+3\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
Here is my "proof":
Since $a,b,c$ are positive reals and $a+b+c=1$, then $0<a,b,c<1$. Thus $\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{a}}$ etc are all positive, so we can use AM-GM to get $$\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{a}}+\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{b}}+\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{c}}\ge 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{(1-\sqrt{a})(1-\sqrt{b})(1-\sqrt{c})}}$$
Equality occurs if and only if $\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{a}}=\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{b}}=\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{c}}$, i.e. $a=b=c$. Since $a+b+c=1$ it follows that equality occurs when $a=b=c=1/3$. Therefore (from our AM-GM application), the minimum value of $\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{a}}+...$ is $3\left(\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{1/3}}\right)=\frac{9+3\sqrt{3}}{2}$. So it follows that $$\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{a}}+\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{b}}+\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{c}}\ge \frac{9+3\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
as required

I'm not sure if this is correct, and would really appreciate if someone could check it for me.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not correct. To understand it, consider the following case : we can see that $f(x)=(5/4)x^2-2x+1\ge (1/4)x^2$ holds for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and that the equality holds if and only if $x=1$, but the minimum value of $f(x)$ is $f(4/5)$, not $f(1)$.

Comment: Whether we use AM-GM or not is not the point, but then how about the following case using AM-GM? "To find the minimum value of $x^2+1$ for $x\ge 0$, using AM-GM inequality gives you $x^2+1\ge 2\sqrt{x^2\cdot 1}=2x$. The equality holds if and only if $x=1$, so the minimum value of $x^2+1$ is $2$." Of course, this is wrong because the minimum value *is* $1$ at $x=0$.

Comment: Then, how about this? "To find the minimum value of $x^2+1$ for $x\ge 1/2$, using AM-GM inequality gives you $x^2+1\ge 2\sqrt{x^2\cdot 1}=2x$. The equality holds if and only if $x=1$, so the minimum value of $x^2+1$ is $2$." This is wrong because the minumum value is $5/4$ at $x=1/2$.

Comment: If $f(x)\ge g(x)$ holds for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and $f(a)=g(a)$, then you can say $g(a)$ is the minimum of $f(x)$ **only when** $g(x)$ is a constant. I would like you to think why. Drawing the graph of the above examples might be helpful.

Comment: (Whether there is another condition or not is not the point. Also, for the second example of yours, what do you mean the minimum of $x+y$? $x+y=2$, isn't it?) Then, for the first example of yours, the main problem is that the RHS of $x^2+1\ge 2x$ is not a constant. For example, "To find the minimum of $x+\frac 1x$ for $x\gt 0$, using AM-GM gives you $x+\frac 1x\ge 2\sqrt{x\cdot \frac 1x}=2$. The equality holds if and only if $x=1$. So, the minimum is $2$ at $x=1$." This is correct because the RHS of $x+\frac 1x\ge 2$ is a constant.

Comment: You know the equality holds when $x=y=1$. This is correct. However, this only means that when $x=y=1$, $x^2+y^2=2xy$ holds. That's all. This **never** states that the minimum of $x^2+y^2$ is attained when $x=y=1$. I've already explained why. Read my commments carefully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17397/discussion-between-mathlove-and-analysis-incarnate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, suppose you have $\mathrm D \subset \mathbb R^n$ and need to minimise $f: \mathrm D \mapsto \mathbb R$.  Note that any side conditions can be incorporated into our definition of $\mathrm D$. Further suppose you have found an inequality of form $f(x) \ge g(x)$, for any $x \in \mathrm D$ and equality is possible when $x=a \in \mathrm D$. Now the question is can you conclude $f(x) \ge g(a)$ for all $x \in \mathrm D$?

In general, the answer is no.  All we need is a counter example, several have been provided in comments above - e.g. take $\mathrm D = [0, 1]$ and $f(x) = x^2+1$.  We can write the inequality $f(x) \ge 2x$ with equality iff $x=1$ by AM-GM, which should have given the minimum as $2$, but clearly $f(0) =1$ is the minimum. The situation is perhaps more obvious from the graph below.

[image]

So under what conditions can we claim we have found a minimum? Clearly if we have the further condition that $\forall x \in \mathrm D, \; g(x) \ge g(a)$, then we can easily conclude $f(x) \ge g(a)$ for all $x \in \mathrm D$, and as $f(a)=g(a)$ can be achieved, this has to be the minimum.  Hence this is a sufficient condition.  Note that $g$ being constant is a special case of this condition and that it is not necessary that the equality is achieved at a unique value.

---

P.S. For your specific inequality, one way would be to note that it is $\sum_{cyc} \left(\dfrac1{1-\sqrt a} -\dfrac{3+\sqrt3}2 \right) \ge 0$.  Using the constraint, we can add any multiple of $\sum_{cyc} (1-3a)$ without changing the inequality.  So it is enough to show that 
$$\frac1{1-\sqrt{a}}-\frac{3+\sqrt3}2 +\frac{3+2\sqrt3}4 (1-3a) \ge 0 \\ \iff \left(\sqrt{a}-\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)^2 \left(\sqrt{a}+\frac2{\sqrt3}-1\right) \ge 0$$

Comment: I have explained more.  Hope that is clearer now.